# UNIX ACL Permissions Different when file is copied from Windows Explorer compared to unix cp command

Tags: permissions, unix, access-control-list, setfacl

Please share your inputs on the following scenario.

Unix Path 1.

Permissions for /source/dir1/test.txt are

```
-rw-rw----+
```

Scenarios

Case 1: When this file is copied from Windows Explorer to the path /source/dir2

permissions become read only for the group:

```
-rw-r----+
```

getfacl text2 shows mask as

```
r--
```

Case 2: Unix cp command is used to test.txt from /source/dir1/ to /source/dir2/

permissions for test.txt in dir2 are

```
-rw-rw----+.
```

getfacl text2 shows mask as

```
rw-
```

For both the scenarios same userid belonging to the same unix group is used.

Do you know why permissions are different ?

1. Is there a trigger or a way that unix server knows that file is being copied by an environment external to unix. ?
2. Since the userid and the group is same is it an ACL setting/rule ?
3. If 2 is yes, what is it ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think we need more context.  In particular, how is Windows Explorer accessing the Unix filesystem?

Comment: Its is through Samba connection

Answer (score 0):

They work with different `umask` settings.

For more details, read https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask .

Comment: Windows Explorer accessing the Unix filesystem thro Samba. nt acl support is set to No in samba configuration file. can you suggest any samba settings to be added/modified?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/210808/ suggests, that Samba overrides your settings in windows.